# How to use a query result as a parameter in the new query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following code, but doesn¡t works.

My intention is to get a result on simple query and use it on a new query. How can I do that?

```
    $datos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vcal_days WHERE CIID='$greatparent_dir' AND DAY='2019-01-01'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $datos ))
{
    //Print "<center>".$info['DID'] . ""; 
    $datos = ['.$info['DID'] .'];
}
$evento = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vcal_event WHERE DID='$datos'") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $eventos ))
{
    Print "<center>".$info['eventtext'] . ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a nested query?

I believe there must a be a primary id in vcal_days table.

Let's assume you have DID column in vcal_days.

Then use this query.

SELECT * FROM vcal_event WHERE DID IN (SELECT DID FROM vcal_days WHERE CIID='$greatparent_dir' AND DAY='2019-01-01')

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is almost correct.

From what I see is that you close the bracket of your first while before using the variable so you override the variable datos multiple time so your second query only have the last value.

But if you put the second query inside the first while, you'll get every one of them.

I don't know about nested query so the answer above might be better, but this one should work too.